# Unable to find element using the following Xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find the input type with statusid_103408 and with text() Draft

[image]

here is the xpath i am using, not sure where I am going wrong

```
//input[@name='statusid_103408' and contains(text(), 'Draft')]
```

Comment: contains is not the right way to go. If you know the whole text, it's better to choose `//input[@name='statusid_103408' and text()='Draft']`

Comment: Your text is not inside the input tag, that's why the problem, just pass the name alone like //input[@name='statusid_103408]

Comment: @gopal, yes i just noticed that. how can i get the statusid_103408 with the text Draft?

Comment: @Jayesh Doolai, no, contain will work fine the problem is, his text is not in input tag

Comment: @Gopal, should i go to the parent li first then find the text?

Comment: Oh ok name is same, so use value it will work.

Comment: ah yes, you are right :(

Comment: thank you it works

Comment: ah, I missed the fact that text is not inside input tag. In that case, the unique thing for that check box is the value.

Comment: I put that as an answer, Hope you would accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this xpath does not work is because the text of "Draft" is not actually a property of the input element. It is contained in the li element that is the parent. Therefore, your search is returning no results.

I suggest just using the name only in your xpath search (if it unique). If you definitely need the text in your search, you can search the li item's text first, then find your input, like so:

```
//li[text()='Draft']/input[@name='statusid_103408']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Value it will work , because value is unique, text is not inside the input tag!